# Changing format from Adobe Acrobat pdf to Jupyter Notebook ipynb

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

Good day,

While downloading my Jupyter notebook ipynb file , the saving format as default changes to PDF Adobe Acrobat and this makes the file unreadable.

I have tried changing the name of the file but still this doesn´t work...

The name for the file would be : abcdefg.ipynb and the type of doc "Adobe Acrobat Document".

I hope you can help me, thank you very much

Comment: you may change last file extension from .pdf to .ipynb and try

Comment: Is the file being downloaded as `notebook.pdf` or `notebook.ipynb`? Where do you download it from? Do you use a browser (which one)? What version of Jupyter notebook interface you use (Jupyter Notebook/JupyterLab/which version).

Answer (score 0):

In Jupyter Lab you should be able to save your notebook by clicking on File > Save Notebook As... If you prefer to save your notebook in a different format than .ipynb, click on File > Export Notebook As...

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding it, but if you want to change a file's extension and you're on windows (8 or 10):

- When saving the file, you should be able to set your own extension if you can set the "save as type" to 'All'
- To rename an existing file's extension, on Explorer go to "View" and make sure "File name extensions" is checked, then rename the file normally

Note that if the file was an actual PDF document, you can't convert it just by renaming the extension. (The same also applies to most other file types)